# How to play X3: Albion Prelude?

Tags: x3-albion-prelude

I am a huge scifi fan and bought the latest X3 package on Steam (Terran Conflict, Albion Prelude).

Although I find those games very interesting, I am not aware of how the frag I have to play them.

I mainly play Albion Prelude, fly around and try to do stuff (e.g. get silicium from an asteroid, try to earn money..). However, when accepting missions I never complete them. They are too difficult for me because sometimes I don't know what to do.

I searched the internet for tutorials, but I did not find one which tells me what to do. For example, I would love to see a tutorial which explains me how to start with the humble merchant or how to built a mine on an asteroid from scratch. I even don't know how to "harvest" minerals from a rock.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the learning curve for x3 is very steep, there are a lot of tutorials on the egosoft forums, those are your best bet.  I could write an entire thesis as an answer to your question and it still wouldn't be enough

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The X3 series is very complex and it can take many hours to gain any significant understanding of the game's mechanics.

At it's core, it's a space trading game.  You want to buy items at places where they are inexpensive, and sell them at places where you can make a profit.  For instance, buy Energy Cells from a Solar Plant, and sell them at a factory or other station that requires them.

Doing this manually takes quite a bit of time and effort, but eventually you'll gain the funds and resources required to command additional ships - you can then send *them* to run these hauling operations for you, earning you cash while you pursue other things.

Eventually you'll get enough money to build your own stations, and then you can make mega profits producing finished goods directly from raw materials.  Then your job becomes one mostly of macro-managing the production chains to ensure that the money continues to flow.

Mining is not something I engaged in much personally, as it tends to require some large ships and a lot of manual effort.  Combat's kind of an advanced subject, as you'll likely have to sink a fair number of credits into a good "dogfighting" ship and the appropriate armaments for it.

If you're having trouble with a specific mission class, you might browse the mission guides on the [X3 Wiki](http://x3wiki.com/index.php/Missions), which contains information about how to complete each type of mission, and what you'll need in order to be successful.

To point you in the right direction for a more in-depth guide, check out the [X3 Handbook](http://apricotmappingservice.com/x3handbook.html) - it's a collection of a number of useful guides generated by the community over the years.  Sometimes the tone is a bit on the "conversational" side for my taste, but it's still chock full of good resources.  There's an emphasis on the Terran Conflict (TC) content in some of the early chapters which you may wish to skip over if you're starting with Albion Prelude.

Comment: Thank you for your extensive reply, I appreciate it! I didn't know about the huge handbook and the wiki, I will try to learn my way through.